# Why is org-mode always uncompressing ob-tangle.el.gz?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I recently shifted over to and wrote a literate init.el in a manner of speaking. Using [this](http://endlessparentheses.com/init-org-Without-org-mode.html) technique, I don't (require 'org-mode).

Suddenly when I open up my .org file to edit it, it consistently hangs for a second on `uncompressing ob-tangle.el.gz...done`.

Since I have started from scratch and had not noticed that at all over the last few days while editing it, was I just blind, or did something happen?

Answer (score 2):

The long and short of it is that I had accidentally modified that file while looking at source. Causing emacs to prefer it over the older bytecompiled version of it.

So on osx I pulled `touch -mt YYYYMMDDhhmm` on the file and rolled it back to earlier than the bytecompiled version.

Comment: Years later, happening to me. I've no idea why. I even purged all straight.el repos.